# `residuals(lm.fit)` in R seems to indicate incorrect number of rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm analyzing the AutoMPG dataset in R, a dataset that is available in the ISLR package and also on the [UC Irvine repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data).

> When I run `residuals(lm.fit)`, the output seems to indicate that there are 397 rows, but `dim(Auto)` and `summary(Auto)` both tell me there are only 392 rows.

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and what this means? Is it an error in my code?

```
    install.packages('ISLR')
    library(ISLR)
    dim(Auto) # 392 9
    str(Auto) # 'data.frame': 392 obs. of 9 variables: ...
    Auto$origin = as.factor(Auto$origin)

    # I use the lm() function to perform a simple 
    # linear regression with mpg as the response 
    # and horsepower as the predictor.
    lm.fit <- lm(mpg~horsepower, data=Auto)
    lm.fit # gives the coefficients as expected
    summary(lm.fit) # gives residuals, etc. as expected 

    # Here's where my question arises. I decide to 
    # explore the residuals:
    residuals(lm.fit) 

    # It outputs what looks to be a list of residuals 
    # from 1 to 397. But the Autos df is actually only 
    # 392 rows.
    1
    -1.41604568519558
    2
    1.10851998218221
    ...
    396
    0.533872913768169
    397
    4.00740711382913
```

My first guess, since there seem to be 5 extra rows, is that the first 5 values are Min 1Q Median 3Q Max. But this is not the case.

To explore, I paste the list into Excel and it turns out there are only 392 rows, even though the first is labeled 1 and the last is labeled 397.

After analyzing the output more closely I see that the results **skip over** 33, 127, 331, 337, and 355. That is, the 33rd observation is labeled 34, the 127th is labeled 129, and so on, thus ending at 397 instead of 392.

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and what this means? Is it an error in my code?

Comment: So the row.names are not sequential and have the "gaps" you identified. I don't see anything in the "output" that indicates the Auto object has 397 rows. In fact the output of `str` that you included says there are 392 rows. Voting to close as user confusion (equivalent to a typo.)

Comment: Confusion would seem to be a valid reason to ask a question, no? What is confusing to me is the output of `residuals()`. The last item is labeled (though apparently not indexed) `397`. Why is *this* label applied here? Intuitively it appears to be an index.

Comment: Row.names do not need to be sequential. This suggests that the author of that package removed some rows that had missing values. If you really want to know "why" you should email the package author. Even the help page, `?Auto` ,says there are only 392 lines of data

Comment: "Row.names need not be sequential." True, of course. I simply expected them to be intuitively meaningful. My bad. I was confused so I asked for clarification. I now see that the rownames mean "the _original_ index of this row, before NA values were removed." That's just not what I intuitively expected from a set of row labels 1,2,3,4,5 ... 394,395,396,397. Without reason to think otherwise, I'd expect ... to mean what it usually means: all ints between. That's all. I understand (now) why that this isn't the case here. But it wasn't clear to me when I first saw the 397 value.

Comment: You weren't alone. The author of that Kaggle page in the answer you accepted made the same mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> dim(Auto)
[1] 392   9
> length(residuals(lm.fit))
[1] 392
```

No error, just the row-names don't line up with their indices. I suspect that there may have been some `NA`s in those rows or something, as there are only complete cases in the dataset:

```
> sum(!complete.cases(Auto))
[1] 0
```

This is more or less confirmed if you look at this [Kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/ishaanv/ISLR-Auto#Auto.csv), you'll see `?` in rows that you specified.

Comment: thanks, yes, I see the missing data in those rows. So did the `lm.fit` function automatically clean the data for me to get rid of (or ignore) those rows? If it is ignoring them without deleting them I can see why the row-names would continue to use their original index values as labels.

Comment: I believe `lm` does automatically remove incomplete cases unless you tell it to do something else with the `na.action` argument. That said, in this case the authors seemed to have removed these rows from the dataset, but kept the unaltered indices as rownames...I do not know why. The `lm` function automatically assigns the rownames to each residual, hence the named vector result.

Comment: Appreciate your help. In the dataset on the UCR website I don't see rownames, but maybe they exist in the ISLR dataset. Will look to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

> Description: 
>   Gas mileage, horsepower, and other information for 392 vehicles.
>
> The orginal data contained 408 observations but 16 observations with missing values were removed.
>
> Source:
>   This dataset was taken from the StatLib library which is maintained at Carnegie Mellon University. The dataset was used in the 1983 American Statistical Association Exposition.

There's a useful lesson here. You should always study the nature of your data *before* doing any analysis. The link to the Kaggle page has some hilarious errors, including the number of rows as well as misspelling the name of the ISLR package. So verify, verify, verify. (Don't even trust.)

Comment: Thanks, pretty much thought that's what I was doing. First I read the description: 392. I did `summary()`: 392. I did `str()`: 392. That's why _later_, when I did `residual()` (397), the difference jumped out at me. Perhaps I am misreading your comment and answer, but the lesson I'm gleaning is **don't** ask.